# Ошибка при сборке FileNotFoundError, но файл есть

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я решил свою недавнюю проблему c PyInstaller, но появилась немного другая и странная. При сборке через код в exe я получаю следующее:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\AdminVM\Desktop\fdf\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 198, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\AdminVM\Desktop\fdf\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\AdminVM\Desktop\fdf\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AdminVM\Desktop\fdf\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 979, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\AdminVM\Desktop\fdf\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 901, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\AdminVM\Desktop\fdf\bh\bh.spec", line 22, in <module>
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
  File "C:\Users\AdminVM\Desktop\fdf\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 97, in __init__
    pyc_path = compile_pymodule(name, src_path, workpath, code_cache=None)
  File "C:\Users\AdminVM\Desktop\fdf\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 721, in compile_pymodule
    with open(src_path, 'rb') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\AdminVM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI29482\\python310.zip\\struct.pyc'
```

Но при всём, при этом, файл по данному пути ЕСТЬ! Я даже больше скажу, если его удалить то он это поймет, ведь ошибка будет другая, на много хуже. И что мне делать я без понятия.

```
subprocess.run(
                    [f'python', '-m', 'PyInstaller',
                     '--onefile',
                     '--windowed',
                     '--noconsole',
                     '--clean',
                     '--workpath', f'{wrkPath}',
                     '--name', f'{nameInput.value}', f'{second_script_path}',
                     f'--distpath', f'{save(pathDIR)}'])
```

(Конечно странно почему еще работает только есть PyInstaller в папке с exe...).

Comment: А код где? С экстрасенсами здесь напряг.

Comment: Ну не знаю конечно зачем тут код, ну добавил только код вызова PyInstaller, хех

Comment: `python310.zip\\struct.pyc` файл в архиве или ты так извращаешься называя так директории?

Comment: Я так не называл, я скачал файлы python из инета, а разархировать не могу, так как в путях конфигурации питона автоматом стоит путь с .zip